# How can this "double exposure" "ghost" photo happen?

Tags: double-exposure

[This youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Fm1VoV0xj-o) shows a person taking photos of her fiance (at the 3:00 mark of the video) and then when they review the photos, there is a partially see through woman behind him in one of the photos:

[image]
[image]

It's obviously not a "ghost", but I'm wondering how this phenomenon can happen. It was taken with a digital camera.

Comment: No-one is going to watch 18 minutes of random youtube video to see if they can find what you're talking about. Be specific. At least a timestamp, or a captured still.

Comment: OK, I watched half of it, after Saaru inlined the images. *"Ooh, spooky"*… can we spell f.a.k.e for hallowe'en? Look, no-one walked past during the take… oh, really, that gives you an even spookier excuse for your fake… I don't buy their cut-in nor their crackly enlargement.

Comment: Now that the reference image is uploaded, the question could be, how a glitch on a digital camera could produce a semi-transparent image like the example.

Comment: Whilst I was watching the video, I saw a strange flash… a subliminal image… maybe a ghost in the background. I managed to get a screenshot… https://i.stack.imgur.com/uZSck.png ;))

Comment: Occam's razor says that if an image looks like a double exposure, the most likely explanation is that it looks like a double exposure because it *is* a double exposure.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not about photography. It's asking about a YouTube video, where only the supposed faulty frame is shown after cut edits. This isn't about the art and business of photography.

Answer (score 1):

Shot in the dark, so to speak...

Reading from the comments its wasn't a "camera" it was an iPhone (authors says in one comment: *"I've been researching about iPhone Portrait mode glitches for days but haven't found any info"*), so some heavy automated post-processing can be assumed.

Given that the picture is taken with the sun in the background, the iPhone software is doing whatever it can to fix things, and it possibly took several shots with different EV settings to blend them (you'll notice that the blend only applies to the darker parts the ghost: hair and cap).

So we can wonder if between some of these shots, the ghost in the background disappeared behind the main subject, so some blending happens  between a shot where the ghost is present and the one where it's not.

Only the developers of the Apple camera software will know...

Comment: Most modern phone cameras do automatic HDR (defaults on for a new phone); this does what you suspect, combines multiple exposures to improve capture of both highlights and shadows.  If something moves in an area that gets blended between two or more exposures, you could get this result -- *exactly* like a double exposure, because it *is* a double exposure.

Answer (score 0):

Some phones claim a ridiculously high resolution.  No way they are using a 40MPixel sensor (or whatever the claim), so they take multiple shots and combine them to give that reported resolution.  Ghosting such as this is just one thing that shows their claim to be misleading.